# Can I create a standalone section after having chapters?

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

I have a document which contains 4 'chapters'. In the end, I am trying to add a Bibliography section but it is getting filed under the last chapter.

I want it as a standalone section.

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

These are the packages I am using.

This is my Index Page

```
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\chaptername{\thechapter}}
\chead{Group Theory}
\rhead{Section\thesection}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\, of $29$}
```

Can anybody help ?
I have two standalone sections titles - Acknowledgements and Certificate but these are there before any of the chapters start.

How can I do the same for the Bibliography part?

Comment: You can try with `\chapter*{Bibliography}`. In any case, we don't know which class are you using and don't know how you include bibliography in your document. How can we answer?

Comment: it's not clear, can you explain more the problem? and what do you mean by filed under the last chapter? can you edit your code to be complete?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `latex-project`?

Comment: ordinarily, in a document with chapters, the bibliography would also be a chapter.  if you insist that it be a section, at the end of the last chapter, add `\cleardoublepage` and then `\section*{Bibliography}`. you will also have to adjust the running heads if it is more than one page long.

Comment: Try \setcounter{chapter}{0} right before the bibliography

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `\front...`, `\main...` and `\backmatter` as well as using pagestyle and `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` (package `chngcntr` this is no problem at all.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{lastpage}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\chaptername{} \thechapter}
\chead{Group Theory}
\rhead{\ifnum\value{section}>0 Section{} \thesection\fi}
\cfoot{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Acknowledgements}
\section{Certificate}

\mainmatter
\counterwithin{section}{chapter}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{First}

\cite{Lam94}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\chapter{Fourth}
\section{First}
\blindtext[10]

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{biblio}


\end{document}
```